# Replace loop and usages with Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Java 8

```
for (SomePojo nsVr : nsVrsList) {
        Optional<MyCustomObject> findMyCustomObject = possibleValues.getValues().stream()
                .filter(possibleValueItem -> possibleValueItem.getName().equals(nsVr.getName()))
                .findAny();
        if (!findMyCustomObject.isPresent()) {
            possibleValues.getValues()
                    .add(new MyCustomObject(nsVr.getInstance(), nsVr.getInstance(), ""));
        }
    }
```

As result then list `possibleValues.getValues()` contain **unique**(no duplicate) items that equal (by name) to items from list `nsVrsList`.
Nice. It's work fine.

But now I want to replace previous code by streams.

```
possibleValues.getValues().addAll(possibleValues
            .getValues().stream().filter(
                    currentPossibleValues -> nsVrsList.stream()
                            .anyMatch(currentSomePojo -> currentPossibleValues.getName()
                                    .equals(currentSomePojo.getName())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But as result the `possibleValues.getValues()` is **empty**.

Comment: Your indentation is very confusing. Besides that, your first code snippet *creates new objects* using `new MyCustomObject(…)` when there is *no* match whereas the second tries to find *all matching elements* of `possibleValues.getValues()`, followed by adding them to `possibleValues .getValues()` again. It should be obvious that they can’t be equivalent when `new MyCustomObject` doesn’t appear in the second code snippet…

Comment: quite hard o get the code to compile for testing what type is `possibleValues`? also give minimal definition of `MyCustomObject` and `SomePojo`

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to have unique value in the possibleValues from the list as I understand.

To make it less computationally intensive, try this:

```
Set<String> existingUniqueValueNames = possibleValues.getValues().stream()
                .map(val -> val.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<MyCustomObject> newValues = nsVrsList.stream()
            .filter(nsVr -> !existingUniqueValueNames.contains(nsVr.getName())).map(nsVr -> {
                return new MyCustomObject(nsVr.getInstance(), nsVr.getInstance(),
                        nsVr.getName());
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Aggregate
possibleValues.getValues().addAll(newValues);
```

**P.S:** If possible, the `possibleValues.getValues()` can be a `Set` instead of a `List` which does all  these above computation by default, provided that you have correct `toString()` on `MyCustomObject`